# How to change row fields to column header in python?

Tags: python, pivot-table, transform, data-cleaning

My data is in below format

```html
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to transform it in below format:

```html
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th></tr>
    <tr><td>A</td><td>A</td><td>A</td><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>D</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td> </td></tr>
    <tr><td> </td><td>D</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried using Excel pivot, Python pivot table but i'm not able to get desired result.

Can you help me please?

Thanks,
Naseer

Comment: Are you using `pandas` as well?

Comment: Ofcourse pandas, I'm trying in R for now aswell.

Comment: what have you tried in `pandas`? Note that your expected output is not a table (probably a typo, but please consider fixing it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. Hope this will help:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':[2,1,3,2],'C':[3,4,2,1],'D':[4,2,1,3]});
data = {'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':[2,1,3,2],'C':[3,4,2,1],'D':[4,2,1,3]}
```

Converting the data into required format..

```
new_data = dict()
for key, value in data.items():
    for data1 in value:
        if data1 in new_data.keys():
            if key in new_data[data1]:
                pass
            else:
                new_data[data1].append(key)
        else:
            new_data[data1]=[key]
```

If the length of values across each key if will not be same, then pandas will not create dataframe for the dictionary passed. Hence converting the value length to same as 4 in this case.

```
for key ,value in new_data.items():
    dif =  4 - len(value)
    new_data[key] = value + [None]*dif
```

Ouput of the data will be :

```
new_data

{1: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 2: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 3: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 4: ['A', 'C', 'D', None]}
```

Now converting it into dataframe:

```
    1   2   3   4
0   A   A   A   A
1   B   B   B   C
2   C   C   C   D
3   D   D   D   None
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shishir for the program. Its as smooth as butter. May you be happy forever!